# DVD Writing - Multiple sessions on original Boot DVD - Boot Failure

Tags: linux, iso-image, bootable-media, dvd-burning, nero

I downloaded LUbuntu ISO from the official site and using Nero 2017 created a bootable DVD (Session 1 ) on Windows 7 PC. I however did not ‘Finalize’ the DVD. So there was about 3 GB free space on it. The resulting DVD was perfectly bootable.

Using Multi session option, later I added some more other files on to the same DVD using Nero 2017 again (Session 2).

However after second session being written to it, the resulting DVD has lost its ability to boot any more.
I just get some Grub prompt and it no longer boots into LUbuntu. The earlier one (The very first session) was perfectly bootable.

I have rechecked this behavior using DVD-RW media. Recreating 2 sessions on DVD-RW disk.Is this how it is or I am making some mistake in burning multi session DVD whereby first session was a bootable ISO file being written on it?